# Distance-2 Edge Coloring

Tags: coloring

Can we convert the problem of distance-2 edge coloring of G(V,E) to correspondig conflict graph G'(V'E') ?

The set of all edges in G are represented as vertex set in G'.
The edge present between two node in G' if both are intefering in G.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "conflict graph", but vertex coloring the line graph $L(G)$ of a graph $G$ gives you its chromatic index, i.e., $\chi'(G) = \chi(L(G))$. This generalizes to distance $k$ as well. For instance, distance 2-edge coloring is equivalent to vertex coloring the 2nd power (i.e. square) of a line graph.